# Whole web client background

Tags: css, flexbox, background-color

I have a problem with my displayed page web, the background color doesn't cover the whole page. Normally it's the :host in my  that does it but it no longer works because

```
  :host{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #282828;
}
```

Like you can see the background wholy wrap the content made and not the whole page and I don't know how to change it.
I would like to conserve the:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
```

of the host since it's needed for the display but make the background color wrap the whole page.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will help me.

[image]

Comment: `:host` is incorrect, should be `.host` assuming a class. Colon is reserved for pseudo selectors.

Comment: @EternalHour But if I do it the background is not taken into account :/

Comment: You need to provide an example including HTML. As I told you in the previous question you asked, we need HTML not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your host container or meta class (in Angular maybe)
does not span the whole view height.
This will do the trick for you:

```css
body {
  background-color: #282828;
}

.host {
border: 1px solid yellow;
color: yellow;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #282828;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="host">
CONTENT GOES IN HERE
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfectly does the trick ! Thanks a lot for the help! And I just re-read what I posted but I thinks the problem came from another component. I sould learn to think before posting :/...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, do you need to do this?

```
body, html {
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0
}
```

If not, could you post a screenshot of the issue you're having?

Comment: I need to keep:  display: flex; flex-grow: 1; flex-direction: column; but I want my background color to cover my whole page